# Empty braces magic in initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++20, initializer-list

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "Default-ctor" << std::endl; }
  X(std::initializer_list<int> l) { 
      std::cout << "Ilist-ctor: " << l.size() << std::endl; 
  }
};

int main() {
    X a{};
    X b({}); // reads as construct from {}
    X c{{}}; // reads as construct from {0}
    X d{{{}}}; // reads as construct from what?
    // X e{{{{}}}}; // fails as expected
}
```

[Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/q1E6v8)

I have no questions about a, b and c, everything is rather clear

But I can not understand why d works

What this additional pair of braces in d stands for? I looked up C++20 standard, but I can not find answer easily. Both clang and gcc agree on this code, so it is me who misses something

Comment: I'm not certain, but it could be a copy/move from another temporary object initialized via the inner braces (and of course wouldn't actually be a copy/move due to C++17's rules).

Comment: @chris I ran it with C++14 and `-fno-elide-constructors` and no constructors were called.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A nice trick to do to get information about what the compiler does, is to compile using all errors:
`-Weverything`. Let's see the output here (for `d` only):

```
9.cpp:16:6: warning: constructor call from initializer list is incompatible with C++98                                                                                            
      [-Wc++98-compat]                                                                                                                                                            
  X d{{{}}}; // reads as construct from what?                                                                                                                                     
     ^~~~~~
```

`X::X(std::initializer_list)` is called.

```
9.cpp:16:8: warning: scalar initialized from empty initializer list is incompatible with                                                                                          
      C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]                                                                                                                                                      
  X d{{{}}}; // reads as construct from what?                                                                                                                                     
       ^~
```

Scalar (`int`) initialized in inner `{}`. So we have `X d{{0}}`.

```
9.cpp:16:7: warning: initialization of initializer_list object is incompatible with                                                                                               
      C++98 [-Wc++98-compat]                                                                                                                                                      
  X d{{{}}}; // reads as construct from what?                                                                                                                                     
      ^~~~                                                                                                                                                                        
5 warnings generated.
```

`std::initializer_list` is initialized from `{0}`. So we have `X d{std::initializer_list<int>{0}};`!

This shows us everything we need. The extra bracket is for constructing the initializer list.

**Note**: If you want to add extra brackets you can by invoking the copy/move constructor (or eliding it), but C++ compilers won't do it implicitly for you to prevent errors:

```
X d{X{{{}}}}; // OK
X e{{{{}}}}; // ERROR
```

Answer (score 12):

Thought I'd just illustrate:

```
X d{               {                       {}        }};
   |               |                       |
   construct an    |                       |
   `X` from ...    an initializer_list     |
                   containing...           int{}
```

The rules for list-initialization are to find an `initializer_list<T>` constructor and use it if at all possible, otherwise... enumerate the constructors and do the normal thing.

With `X{{}}`, that is list-initialization: the outermost `{}`s are the `initializer_list` and this contains one element: the `{}`, which is `0`. Straightforward enough (though cryptic).

But with `X{{{}}}`, this doesn't work anymore using the outermost `{}` as the `initializer_list` because you can't initialize an `int` from `{{}}`. So we fallback to using constructors. Now, one of the constructors takes an `initializer_list`, so it's kind of like starting over, except that we'd already peeled off one layer of braces.

---

This is why for instance `vector<int>{{1, 2, 3}}` works too, not just `vector<int>{1, 2, 3}`. But like... don't.

Comment: Thanks, I already accepted first answer but this is great explanation as well. Btw, I found even more intersting example of brace madness: std::vector<std::string> vs = {{{{{}}}}};

Here, following your explanation string is constructed from {{}} and vector from {{s}} with uniform initialization {v}, wow...